# WPF Button text not changing is my UI locked up from threading code

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working with a basic paint program and I wrote some save code that exports the current paint window to a png file. I changed that code to execute on a new thread or so I thought. However when I run code that changes my Save buttons text it doesn't update until after the image has been saved.

My first thing that is weird I can place a break point at the line in SaveBtnClick that changes the text to "Saving" and that doesn't effect the button. I realize that the code executing in the SaveAsPngAsync is still locking my UI up. I think that is because of the `scheduler` that I pass to it, but without that block of code I get an error talking about the threads STA.

Code:

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeSaveBtnText("Saving");
            if (pictureSaveTask == null)
            {
                pictureSaveTask = SaveAsPngAsync();
                pictureSaveTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    pictureSaveTask = null;
                    ChangeSaveBtnText("Save");

                });
            }
            else
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                ChangeSaveBtnText("Save");
            }

        }

        private void ChangeSaveBtnText(string text)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => {
                SaveBtn.Content = text;
            }));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the current state of the DrawingCanvas as Xaml so that it can re parsed on a different thread then exported as a png.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Task of executing code</returns>
        private async Task SaveAsPngAsync()
        {
            //Stores current DrawingCanvas at time of save as a string to be parsed later.
            var canvasAtSaveState = XamlWriter.Save(DrawingCanvas);
            var ActualWidth = DrawingCanvas.ActualWidth;
            var ActualHeight = DrawingCanvas.ActualHeight;

            //Not really sure why this is required but without, throws Error: Thread must be STA.
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            //This is the short hand way of creating a task and running it instantly
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                try
                {
                    // 'as' object syntax is a short hand conversion
                    InkCanvas cc = XamlReader.Parse(canvasAtSaveState) as InkCanvas;

                    //Pretty clear that this gets the users path to their desktop
                    var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

                    //File stream is the easiest way to export a stream of bytes into a file
                    //Important usage of a C# syntax "using" statements are very important to prevent memory leaks especially with streams
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "picture.png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        //Must use Actual(Value) because Simply using Width or Height doesn't change the window size changes or scales
                        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);

                        rtb.Render(cc);

                        //PngBitmapEncoder because my InkCanvas has a transparent background
                        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

                        //Adds a single frame to the image because this isn't a Gif
                        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

                        //Begins saving the pngBytes into a stream that will then store the bytes into a file
                        pngEncoder.Save(fs);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Catches anything just in case something explodes
                }
            }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, scheduler); //PreferFairness tells the thread pool that this new worker thread isn't super important
        }
```

Comment: Your task is running synchronously in the UI thread, that's why you don't see the button updated. You're not `await`ing your task in the button click handler.

Comment: You have plenty of confusing points here: scheduler, creation options, token, async/await in the `SaveAsPngAsync`. None of which you need. Removing all those will make it working as intended.

Comment: @Sinatr I disagree, I want a token for canceling the save operation, I gave it a scheduler because I get exceptions talking about STA for my thread.

Comment: I have reworked my code and it runs on a different thread independent of the UI thread now.

Comment: I have decided that the code runs so fast that leaving the png encoding stuff on the UI makes no difference you cannot even see it execute. Also indicating save status doesn't matter because it happens so fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your async code should look like this:

```
class YourClass
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private async void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if cts isn't null, then a saving task is already running -> cancel it
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise, create a new token source and await the saving task
            // this runs on the UI thread
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            SaveBtn.Content = "Saving";
            try
            {
                // the task itself will probably run on a thread pool's thread,
                // but after it finishes, this method will continue on the UI thread
                await Task.Run(() => SaveAsPng(cts.Token), cts.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // insert your cancellation handling if needed
                // this runs on the UI thread
            }
            finally
            {
                // This runs on the UI thread
                SaveBtn.Content = "Save";
                cts.Dispose();
                cts = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveAsPng(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // your synchronous implementation
        // don't forget to check ct.IsCancellationRequested in this method
        // or call ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

        // no need to start any tasks here
        // don't use dispatchers, schedulers etc.
        // just a plain old synchronous code
    }
}
```